# kivy BoxLayout is not displaying my image when using vertical orientation?

Tags: python-3.x, kivy

i am using kivy BoxLayout with two Buttons, one of the buttons is to display an image. the image displays fine when using the horizontal orientation, but when I use the vertical orientation it will not display my image. windows 10, python 3.6.4, kivy 1.10.0

.py file:

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.core.window import Window

from kivy.uix.label import Label
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager, Screen
from kivy.properties import ObjectProperty
from kivy.uix.stacklayout import StackLayout
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout

class ClickerScreen(Screen):
    pass

class Manager(ScreenManager):
    clicker_screen = ObjectProperty(None)

class ClickerApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return Manager()

if __name__=='__main__':
    ClickerApp().run()
```

.kv file:

```
#: import Window kivy.core.window.Window
<Manager>:
    id: screen_manager

    clicker_screen: clicker_screen

    ClickerScreen:
        id: clicker_screen
        name: 'clicker'
        manager: screen_manager

        BoxLayout:
            orientation: 'vertical'

            Button:
                background_color: 0,0,0,0

                Image:
                    source: 'Images/button.png'
                    allow_stretch: False
                    keep_ratio: True
                    size: self.parent.size

            Button:
```

Comment: Can you provide minimal reproducible code and details of your environment?

Comment: windows 10, python 3.6.4, kivy 1.10.0

Comment: @MikhailGerasimov it also does the same thing under linux system. other programs work just fine.